# mondrian dimension cache not getting flushed

Tags: caching, mondrian, saiku

I am trying to flush the mondrian dimension cache by following code -

```
     org.olap4j.metadata.Schema OlapSchema = olapConnection.getOlapSchema();
     NamedList<org.olap4j.metadata.Cube> cubeList =  OlapSchema.getCubes();
     org.olap4j.metadata.Member m = null;
     for(org.olap4j.metadata.Cube cube: cubeList) {
    m = cube.lookupMember(IdentifierNode.parseIdentifier( "[Time].[2013].[Jul2013]").getSegmentList());
       final CacheControl cacheControl = olapConnection.getCacheControl(null);
       CacheControl.MemberSet regionTime = cacheControl.createMemberSet(mondrian.olap.Member)m, false);
       cacheControl.flush(regionTime);

     }
```

But this code is throwing a runtime error "MondrianOlap4jMember and mondrian.olap.member are incompatible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to do the following to flush the cache - 
unwrap the member object returned by lookupMember function using [Olap wrapper class](http://www.olap4j.org/api/org/olap4j/OlapWrapper.html?is-external=true) like so -

m = cube.lookupMember(IdentifierNode.parseIdentifier( "[Time].[2013].[Jul2013]").getSegmentList());
OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper)m;
mondrian.olap.Member MondrianMember =  wrapper.unwrap(mondrian.olap.Member.class);

And now call the flush method -

cacheControl.flush(MondrianMember);